# Vim writing 10 of GB-s of disk space, but can't find it with du

Tags: disk-usage

I'm using vim to code with quite a few plugins and it seems that over a few hours something vim is calling is writing my disk full (I have 102 GB free space currently, before closing vim I had 0 space left). The thing is, that if I do `du -h --max-depth=1` in / and add all the folders it seems I should have at least 90 GB of free space. How do I find out what files are being written that take up so much space? Is a temporary file not being deleted properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Program [lsof](https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof) can be used to determine open files by a process. To list files open by vim:

```
lsof -c vim
```

(end output with `C-C`). Other than that, [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) offers a convenient TUI to visualize disk usage, and

```
vim -u NORC
```

starts vim without loading plugins.